# How to back up LXD containers on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: backup, lxd

I am very new to LXD, and am liking it a lot!  My one challenge I have not overcome though is backups.

There are a few containers that I want to run that I would really like to have a backup of, and to be honest I am having a hard time finding a good tutorial or overview for this process.

I don't need backups that are automatic and happen all the time, a manual process is fine.  Just want to know the right way to backup a container, and restore it after a total loss of the HDD on the host.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this as well and found this page.  For now, the upstream LXD devs have [this page on LXD backups](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/backup.md).

The simplest and easiest for me is:

---

## Secondary LXD

This requires a second LXD instance to be setup and reachable from the LXD instance that is to be backed up. Then, all containers can be copied to the secondary LXD instance for backup.

---

So basically, `lxc copy <container> remote:<container>`